Changing Document Library settings in Sharepoint Online using MS Graph / SPO REST does not seem to work
I'm working on a data abstraction layer for SPO in Python. For my application to work, I have to setup its document library in the Sharepoint tenant and ensure that this has got minor versions turned on so I'd like to make sure that the abstraction layer can handle document library settings updates.
I'm doing all other data manipulation for SPO via MS Graph and would prefer to do this one in the same way, if at all possible.
I need to find a way for my third-party app to update the document library settings, so if this is not possible using MS Graph, I'd love some pointers to what I'm supposed to use instead.
Below is the code I'm using, however running this gives me a thumbs up, but only the name properties are updated. I also don't seem to be able to even retrieve the related properties via MS Graph (looks like EDM doesn't have the properties in question, which sounds crazy...).
def update_library(self, site_id: str, drive_id: str, library_properties: dict, new_name: str = None):
    # Get the access token for the Microsoft Graph API
    access_token = self.get_access_token('https://graph.microsoft.com/.default')

    # Convert the drive ID to a list ID
    list_id = self.drive_id_to_list_id(site_id, drive_id)

    # Microsoft Graph API endpoint to update a list
    url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}'

    # Headers for the PATCH request
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    # Data for the PATCH request
    data = library_properties.copy()  # Start with a copy of library_properties

    # Only add 'displayName' and 'name' to data if new_name is not None
    if new_name:
        data.update({
            'displayName': new_name,
            'name': new_name,
        })

    try:
        print(f"PATCH data: {data}")
        # Make the PATCH request
        response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception if the request failed

        print(f"Library '{list_id}' has been updated.")

        # Get the updated library details
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'})
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception if the request failed

        print(f"Updated library details: {response.json()}")
        return SPOLibrary.from_dict(response.json())

    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print(f"Error updating library: {str(e)}")
        print(f"HTTP Status Code: {e.response.status_code}")
        print(f"HTTP Response Content: {e.response.content.decode('utf-8')}")
        raise

Here are print-outs from the terminal when executing the method:
PATCH data:
{   
    'enableVersioning': True, 
    'enableMinorVersions': True, 
    'contentTypesEnabled': True, 
    'hidden': True
}

Library 'd0df80ac-6df7-4354-a0be-5085b3cb2f4e' has been updated.

Updated library details:
{  
    '@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('*site*')/lists/$entity",   
    '@odata.etag': '"d0df80ac-6df7-4354-a0be-5085b3cb2f4e,13"', 
    'createdDateTime': '2024-05-20T17:04:19Z', 
    'description': '', 
    'eTag': '"d0df80ac-6df7-4354-a0be-5085b3cb2f4e,13"', 
    'id': 'd0df80ac-6df7-4354-a0be-5085b3cb2f4e', 
    'lastModifiedDateTime': '2024-05-22T09:32:25Z', 
    'name': 'Testing', 'webUrl': '*sitePath*/Testing', 
    'displayName': 'testing', 
    'createdBy': {'user': {'displayName': 'SharePoint App'}}, 
    'lastModifiedBy': {'user': {'displayName': 'SharePoint App'}}, 
    'parentReference': {'siteId': '*siteId*'}, 
    'list': {'contentTypesEnabled': False, 'hidden': False, 'template': 'documentLibrary'}
}

